# Having problems with thrust and acceleration in python turtle module

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

I am trying to code a boat that keeps its momentum after letting go of "w". However, i also want it to slow down gradually after letting go of "w". I have gotten a decent boat working but sometimes when I press "w" after going a certain direction, the boat goes flying. Is there any way to add a top speed or make it slow down?

```
self.thrust = 0.0
self.acceleration = 0.0001




self.dx += math.cos(math.radians(self.heading)) * self.thrust
self.dy += math.sin(math.radians(self.heading)) * self.thrust




def accelerate(self):
    self.thrust += self.acceleration

def decelerate(self):
    self.thrust = 0
```

Comment: Please extend your example to include how do you actually bind this logic to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to slow down gradually when you aren't pressing "w", then you may want it to go at the same speed, or faster. This code will work for it to go at the same speed. This should work in any Python IDE.

Suppose your boat is a turtle.

```
import turtle
Win = turtle.screen()
Boat = turtle.Turtle()
```

If you want it to also look like a Boat, you can do:

```
screen.adshape(Saved Document Direction)
Boat.shape(Saved Document Direction)
```

Otherwise, you can create your own shapes.
Now, we want it to go at a constant speed, while you press "w":
So:

```
def Constant_Speed():
    Boat.speed(Speed You Want it to Go)
Win.listen()
Win.onkeypress(Constant_Speed, "w")
```

Otherwise, it should slow down.

```
Initial_Speed = Initial Speed
Boat.speed(Initial_Speed)
Initial_Speed *= Fraction of what you want it to be in/decimal
```

So, this should work if you replace with your variables:

```
import turtle
Win = turtle.screen()
Boat = turtle.Turtle()
screen.adshape(Saved Document Direction)
Boat.shape(Saved Document Direction)
def Constant_Speed():
    Boat.speed(Speed You Want it to Go)
Win.listen()
Win.onkeypress(Constant_Speed, "w")
Initial_Speed = Initial Speed
Boat.speed(Initial_Speed)
Initial_Speed *= Fraction of what you want it to be in/decimal and must be less than 1
```

But what if you want it to go faster, not at a constant speed?
Then go to the `def Constant_Speed()` part.
You can rename it: `def Go_Faster()`
Now, the code:

```
Speed = Initial_Speed
Boat.speed(Speed)
Speed *= Times you want to increase speed by
```

Also:
Change the last line to:

```
Initial_Speed2 = Initial Speed * Fraction of what you want it to be in/decimal and must be less than 1
```

With your variables.
Now, this should work:

```
import turtle
Win = turtle.screen()
Boat = turtle.Turtle()
screen.adshape(Saved Document Direction)
Boat.shape(Saved Document Direction)
def Go_Faster():
    Speed = Initial_Speed()
    Boat.speed(Speed)
    Speed *= Times you want to increase by
Win.listen()
Win.onkeypress(Constant_Speed, "w")
Initial_Speed = Initial Speed
Boat.speed(Initial_Speed)
Initial_Speed2 = Initial Speed * Fraction of what you want it to be in/decimal and must be less than 1
```